# What happens when the sender run out of gas in the middle of a function execution?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

Suppose we have a contract with the following defined function:

```
   function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
```

and suppose that sender runs out of gas just after the following line:

```
balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
```

What happened with the state variables? Are incomplete tx included in the block or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "runs out of gas"? Is that a Solidity thing or are you using a turn of phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction that runs out of gas will fail and none of the state variables will be updated. Failed transactions are still included in a block, as you can see in [this `out of gas`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbf7146c7799b8c1e486260726ad5f383f1e98ee9c726b6a76a7e4d1e57f7c298) example.

In your example, `balances[msg.sender] -= result` will not be executed, and `balances[msg.sender]` will remain the exact same as before the transaction.

The sender of the transaction will still pay a fee to the miner for including the transaction in the block.

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7so0vx/my_eth_transaction_failed_what_happens_next/dt6ds2y) post does a good job of walking through various failure scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

If you run out of gas in the middle of a transaction it will fail. You will only pay for the computation used, meaning that all the gas used until it failed will **not** be returned, but the rest will.

You can read more about gas in this chapter of the [Ethereum Book](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#transaction-gas)